# Change the user-agent string for selenium web driver using javascript and phantomjs

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Using javascript is there any way that I could change the PhantomJS user agent to emulate a mobile device?

Comment: Are you using the javascript bindings for selenium-webdriver or are you using webdriver-io? Are you even using javascript?

Comment: Using the javascript bindings. So I have a driver that is saved to `this.driver` and I could call things like `this.driver.get('http://www.google.com')`